# How to delete multiple directories having same prefix name?

Tags: php, filesystems, directory, rmdir

I know that we can delete a directory with the function:

```
rmdir($path);
```

However I wanted to delete a set of directories having the same prefix.
For example there are the directories:

A_Folder1, A_Folder2, A_Folder3, B_Folder1, B_Folder2, B_Folder3

Then I wanted to delete all folders having prefix "A_" only.

Comment: Use `glob()` to get the list, then delete one by one http://php.net/glob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be implemented for example as follow:

```
<?php

    $dir = '/path/to/some/dir/'; // notice: trailing slash!
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if (is_dir($dir . $entry) && strtolower(substr($entry, 0, 2)) == 'a_') {
                rmdir($dir . $entry);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Comment: you must also check if it `is_dir()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 easy ways :

```
exec('rm -rf PREFIX*');
```

or you can use `glob` and `is_dir` functions